# Backbone subviews and switch

Tags: design-patterns, backbone.js, view, subviews

Out of the blue, how does it look ? ActiveWindow is like the main container and below the subviews. Router trigger activewindow.render(options) then the switch operates.
Is it fine to do that ? Or how bad it is ?

```
define('activewindowView', [
    'backbone',
    'text!views/activewindowView/activewindowTemplate.html',
    'ghostviewHunter',
    'menuView',
    'commercesView',
    'horairesView',
    'servicesView',
    'destinationsView',
    'breadcrumbView',
    'staytunedView',
    'helpView',
    'transportsView',
    'aroundView',
    'infoslegalesView',
    'royalsliderView',
    'anomalieView',
    'anomalieReportView',
    'searchView'
    ], function(Backbone, ActivewindowTemplate, GhostviewHunter, MenuView, CommercesView, HorairesView, ServicesView, DestinationsView, BreadcrumbView, StaytunedView, HelpView,
     TransportsView, AroundView, InfoslegalesView, RoyalsliderView, AnomalieView, AnomalieReportView, Searchview) {

    var ActivewindowView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#activewindow',

        template: _.template(ActivewindowTemplate),

        events: {},

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderSubview');
        },

        render: function(options) {
            this.$el.html(this.template(options));
            this.renderSubview(options);
        },

        renderSubview: function(options) {
            // create fil d'ariane view
            this.breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbView();
            GhostviewHunter.addView(this.breadcrumbView);
            // render activewindow subview
            switch(options.subview) {
                case 'menu':
                    this.menuView = new MenuView();
                    this.menuView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.menuView);
                    break;
                case 'commerces':
                    this.commercesView = new CommercesView(options);
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.commercesView);
                    break;
                case 'horaires':
                    this.horairesView = new HorairesView();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.horairesView);
                    break;
                case 'services':
                    this.servicesView = new ServicesView(options);
                    //this.servicesView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.servicesView);
                    break;
                case 'destinations':
                    this.destinationsView = new DestinationsView(options);
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.destinationsView);
                    break;
                case 'staytuned':
                    this.staytunedView = new StaytunedView(options);
                    this.staytunedView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.staytunedView);
                    break;
                case 'help':
                    this.helpView = new HelpView();
                    this.helpView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.helpView);
                    break;
                case 'transports':
                    this.transportsView = new TransportsView(options);
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.transportsView);
                    break;
                case 'around':
                    this.aroundView = new AroundView(options);
                    this.aroundView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.aroundView);
                    break;
                case 'infoslegales':
                    this.infoslegalesView = new InfoslegalesView();
                    this.infoslegalesView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.infoslegalesView);
                    break;
                case 'royalslider':
                    this.royalsliderView = new RoyalsliderView(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.royalsliderView);
                    break;
                case 'anomalie':
                    this.anomalieView = new AnomalieView(options);
                    this.anomalieView.render();
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.anomalieView);
                    break;
                case 'anomalieReport':
                    this.anomalieReportView = new AnomalieReportView(options);
                    this.anomalieReportView.render(options);
                    this.breadcrumbView.render(options);
                    GhostviewHunter.addView(this.anomalieReportView);
                    break;
                /*case 'search':
                    this.*/
            }
        }

    });

    return ActivewindowView;

})
```

Comment: That should work. Another option is, if you can, pass a reference to a view constructor as `options.subview`, then do `this.subview = new options.subview(options)`. Or if you can't do that, you could have an object that snags the right view. `views = {menu:MenuView,..., commerces:CommercesView}`, then `this.subview = new views[options.subview](options);`. Anyway, there's more than one way to a skin a cat.

Comment: I find this question useful and clear but it its rather suited for [codereview.se].